# dropdown menu in actionbar overlaps the actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

i have a menu in the action bar

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.Blog.gkgyan.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:title="@string/action_share"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_rate"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_important"
        android:orderInCategory="102"
        android:title="@string/action_rate"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="103"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menuSortNewest"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="Gk"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menuSortRating"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="Current Affairs"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_pin"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_make_available_offline"
        android:orderInCategory="105"
        android:title="@string/action_pin"
         app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

here is the style applied to the menu

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.



    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.



        -->

    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

    </style>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="@android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
    </resources>
```

my activity

uses

```
public class DetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener{
```

my problem is the dropdown menu is created however it over laps the actionbar i tried 
`<item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>` however it doenot work

i am using

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

target and build versions

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the desired behaviour according to new design guidelines. You are using `appCompat` so it is supposed to happen. see
[Menus - Component](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html)

Update: If you still don't want the overflow menu to overlap action bar, you will have to override overflow menu style from `appCompat`. This might work

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
        <!-- Required for pre-Lollipop. -->
        <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>

        <!-- Required for Lollipop. -->
        <item name="android:overlapAnchor">false</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```